# Nodejs postgres pg syntax error

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

As the title says, I'm running into a syntax error using `node-postgres`. Here's what the code looks like

```
const {Pool, Client} = require('pg')
const pool = new Pool({
  user: '<user>',
  host: '<host>',
  database: '<database>',
  password: '<pw>',
  port: <port>
})

let query = `SELECT * FROM user JOIN notifications ON user.user_id = notifications.user_id WHERE user_id=$1`

let values = ["123"]

pool.query(query, values)
  .then(() => { /* do something */} )
  .catch((err) => { console.log(err)} )
```

Based on this query, I get a syntax error with the message

```
syntax error at or near "."
```

Since the same query runs fine in pgAdmin, my guess is that it's module specific, but I haven't figured out what the problem is.

Any help much appreciated!

Edit: added missing bracket, thanks to Sreeragh A R

Comment: For me it is working..

Comment: A bracket is missing in last line. Change it to



.catch((err) => { console.log(err)} )

Comment: @SreeraghAR thanks, fixed it. However, that was a typo from making it a minimal example. Brackets are correct in original code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`user` is reserved word in postgresql you have to escape `user` using double quotes

```
let query = `SELECT * FROM "user" JOIN notifications ON "user".user_id = notifications.user_id WHERE "user".user_id=$1`
```

Comment: Ah I see. Never know this.

Comment: cheers! that fixes the initial problem. However, now I get a different error message `error: column reference "user_id" is ambiguous`. Is that due to my table set up or again something postgres specific? Edit: nevermind, added "user".user_id to the WHERE statement and that fixed it.